# for loop to determine mutually exclusive/exhaustive network membership

Tags: r

I want to run a for loop that assigns group_ids to a dataset that have two columns, name and location. The goal is to plot large mutually exclusive and exhaustive networks. it is sort of like contract tracing, where individuals interact with locations and then, as a function of both individual interaction and locations, you get a finite network of people who belong to a group. So A and C both interact with location B. Both A and C are in the same group, but so is every other person who interacted with location B. Likewise, any other locations, x1-xn, that interacted with A or C or anyone else from location B is part of the same group. And so forth.

Basically, in the for loop, I want to do the following. First, for the first row in the dataframe, I want to check if the name exists in the name_group_id list initialized. If it does, then assign the group_id associated with that name. If not, then check if the location exists in the location_group_id list. If it does, return that group_id, if it does not, then create a new group_id and add this row's name/group_id to the name_group_id and the location/group_id to the location_group_id

This code does not work yet, as row three should have group_id 1 because name interacted with location 1 in row 1. But it seems close. Help tweaking this code would be awesome.

Thanks, everyone.

```
# Create data frame with the sample data
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "g", "g", "h"),
                 location = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9, 10, 5))

# Initialize two lists
name_id <- list()
location_id <- list()

# Counter for creating new group IDs
group_id_counter <- 0

# For loop that implements the logic
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  row <- df[i, ]
  name <- row$_name
  location <- row$location

  # Check if the name exists in name_id
  if (name %in% names(name_id)) {
    group_id <- name_group_id[[name]]
  } else {
    # Check if the location exists in location_group_id
    if (location  %in% names(location _group_id)) {
      group_id <- location _group_id[[location ]]
    } else {
      group_id_counter <- group_id_counter + 1
      group_id <- paste0("Group ", group_id_counter)
      name_id[[name]] <- group_id
      location _group_id[[location ]] <- group_id
    }
  }

  # Assign the group_id to the current row
  df[i, "group_id"] <- group_id
}
```

Right now, this code would return group_id 2 to row three, but it should be group_id 1 because location 1 was already seen in row 1 and assigned group_id 1. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Expected results for the fake data frame supplied are:

```
name location   Group ID
a   1   1
a   2   1
b   1   1
b   3   1
b   4   1
c   3   1
c   2   1
d   5   2
d   6   2
e   7   3
e   8   3
f   4   1
g   9   4
g   10  4
h   5   2
```

Comment: This sounds like a graph theory problem that's probably a 1- or 2-liner if you use the `igraph` package. Would you be okay not using loops and using `igraph` instead?

Comment: I tried igraph, but my data set has 7.5 million distinct pairs and igraph aborts R when I try.  If there is a way to extract network membership from igraph without plotting anything, for example, I could try again, but do worry my machine cannot handle it.

Comment: Yeah, you certainly don't have to plot a graph to use `igraph`.

Comment: Would you be able to potentially supply some code to use igraph to then save the cluster/network Id to a dataframe? I can try it out on a sample, say 10000, and see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gregor Thomas mentioned this is the same as determining connected components in graphs. Another term for this is equivalence groups. The code below is a bit of hack using an internal function of one of my packages (on CRAN); you could do this using the external functions but then you have to convert the data into the right form; this is easier:

First make a list of all node 'identifiers':

```
x <- c(unique(df$name), unique(df$location))
```

Determine which nodes belong to the same group

```
res <- reclin2:::equivalence(x = x,
  df$name, df$location)
```

The result `res` is a vector with identifiers for each group for each value in `x`. To get the end result:

```
res[match(df$name, x)]
```

Edit: the OP mentioned that the datasets are large; this should work on large datasets.

Comment: Jan, this seems like a promising approach. When I try it out, and then try to add the vector, res, as a column to the dataframe, I get a mismatch error, where the vector has a greater length than the vector has 18 rows and the df has only 15. Any ideas because this is otherwise seeming like a great approach. Thanks!

Comment: Is this with the provided example? In my case the result of the last line `res[matc(df$name, x)]` equals the number of rows in `df`? The code does assume that the identifiers used in location and name are different. In the example this is the case.

Comment: Jan, I found the problem and it is me. Your solution is excellent. Thank you!